# Comparing the distributions of two processes, one of which is constrained by zero

Tags: distributions, markov-process, zero-inflation

I have two continuous stochastic Markov processes: the concentration readout of two proteins in a cell over time. These are shown in this figure, where the blue line is the unbounded protein, and all other lines are zero bounded proteins, but I am interested in just one of them. (The y axis is concentration, and sorry for the poor quality image).

[image: Protein concentrations over time]

In an oversimplified model, the two proteins are produced under the same regime and therefore their concentration distributions (over the whole simulation period) should be identical. However the concentration of protein 1 is close to zero, so is zero-inflated.

Maybe there is a proper terminology which I am neglecting because I don't know the field, but I want to say that the distributions of the driving processes for the two proteins are the same, but the resultant protein concentration distributions are different, (Gaussian and Gamma maybe?) seen in the figure below. This is the case for my simplistic model containing these two proteins.

[image: These are the concentration distributions I get]

Now in the real biological system, experiments show a similar pattern, the concentration distribution over the observation period looks Gaussian for the non-bounded protein, but long-tailed for the zero-bounded protein. I want to know whether they are driven by the same process. Is there some way I can compare their distributions, accounting for the fact that one of them is bounded at zero?

*I.e.* I want to ask, is the difference in the two distributions explained fully by the fact that one of them is close to zero, or is there another difference.

Is this possible? Please let me know if I have not phrased this clearly, or need to include more information.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution In the case where you don't see a normal distribution due to the folding near zero.

Comment: It is not the same as taking absolute values. If something causes the concentration to decrease, it will not increase instead once it hits zero. It will stay there, until it increases again. The best thing I can find is a zero-inflated distribution, but I don't know how to check that the bounded protein is equivalent to the unbounded but just zero inflated.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your issue, but what about fitting a mixture model to your data, and comparing the "non-zero part" to the distribution of the non-bounded protein?

Comment: what happens when you graph the diff processes?

Comment: @EricBrady, yes that sounds great. Could you outline the process in a little more detail as an answer?

Comment: @Aksakal, I tried that, but the time steps are too small for it to tell me anything. Is there a way of overcoming this? Maybe sampling and interpolating, but I am worried about introducing more error.

Comment: What do you mean by to small? Can you show or describe what you see? Acf, pacf, xcorrelation

Comment: Well I was just looking at them with a histogram. But if there is a better way, could you explain please? The histogram is just a single bar, and the plotted diffs look like a bunch of vertical lines equally distributed above and below zero.

Comment: The difference between two graphs is important. Do the histograms look similar?

Comment: All concentrations are bounded at zero, as there is no physical meaning of a negative concentration. When you say zero-bounded do you just mean that the protein's concentration is close to zero a lot of the time?

Comment: It is common for biological concentrations to be heteroscedastic in that the variability of high concentrations is larger than  that of smaller concentrations. Your data look like that. Try a log transformation of the concentrations to see if it makes the distributions more readily interpreted. (Or a square root transformation if there are real zero values.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Matlab based on the graph, but I don't have access to that at the moment so the below example is in R.  I tried to generate a mixture model of a gamma and normal which looks reasonably like your data.  My thought was that after fitting this model, you could either compare the parameter estimates of the normal component to the other distribution, or run a GOF test comparing the normal component to the other data.

Specify parameters for normal/ gamma mixture

```
mu <- 1000
s <- 300
p <- 0.6
shape <- 1.2
rate <- 1/ 300
```

Generate normal gamma mixture

```
whichMix <- rbinom(1000, 1, p)
mixSample <- rep(NA, 1000)
mixSample[which(whichMix == 1)] <- rgamma(sum(whichMix), shape, rate)
whichMix <- -1 * (whichMix - 1)
mixSample[which(whichMix == 1)] <- rnorm(sum(whichMix), mu, s)
```

Estimate mixture model

```
require(flexmix)
fit <- flexmix(mixSample ~ x, k = 2, model = list(FLXMRglm(mixSample ~ 1),
                                                  FLXMRglm(mixSample ~ 1, family = "Gamma")))

summary(fit)
parameters(fit)
```

We get estimated values reasonably close to the true mixture:

```
> parameters(fit)
[[1]]
                   Comp.1   Comp.2
coef.(Intercept) 226.3455 992.6114
sigma            154.6702 293.0577

[[2]]
                      Comp.1       Comp.2
coef.(Intercept) 0.004418025  0.001007444
shape            1.414647496 11.463064235
```

GOF test:

```
ks.test(mixSample[fit@cluster == 2], rnorm(1000, 1000, 300))
D = 0.058, p-value = 0.1994
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```